# bath loop with mysql - how to use loop item in query

Tags: bash

I have the below script. I want to execute the same query over and over again, with different dates.

The below doesn't work because it says $i is not valid

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in '2022/08/30' '2022/08/31'
do
    mysql --host=myhost --user=myusr --password=mypass -e 'select * from db.table where dt = $i'
done
```

Comment: Change `'select * from db.table where dt = $i'` to `"select * from db.table where dt = $i"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes do not do variable expansion.

It should be:

```
mysql --host=myhost --user=myusr --password=mypass -e "select * from db.table where dt = $i"
```